# How to link objects animations in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uianimation

I'll make this as simple as I can.

I have a UIView in the shape of a balloon that floats around its original center. I want to add a line (to look as the rope) and I want it to be linked with its animation, as it turns out, drawing a line isn't as simple as adding a UIView, and the UIview doesn't include the line in it, it's a View Controller containing both.

How can I link both of them so that when the Balloon animates to a different position, the line end that touches the balloon animates with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way I could find around this was through NSNotification Center.